# Does Django's get_queryset() in admin prevent malicious object saving?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am developing a multi-tenant app in Django. In the Django admin, some querysets are filtered based on the user, using `get_queryset()`.

Up till now, when a user updated an object from the Django change form, I would validate the data by creating a `ModelAdmin` form using a factory function to capture the `HttpRequest` object, then ensure that the `Guest` object's `user` was the current user:

**EXAMPLE**

*models.py*

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    guest_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

*admin.py*

```
@admin.register(Guest)
class GuestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request)
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.form = _guest_admin_form_factory(request)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

*forms.py*

```
def _guest_admin_form_factory(request):
    class GuestAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Guest
            exclude = []

         def clean_user(self):
             user = self.cleaned_data.get('user', None)
             if not user:
                 return user
             if user != request.user:
                 raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid request.')
             return user
    return GuestAdminForm
```

It occurred to me that Django might use the `get_queryset()` method to validate this for me, since some simple logging showed that the method is called twice when an object gets updated from the change form.

Is this the case, or do I need to stick to validating through a `ModelAdmin` form?

Comment: Per Mr. Henry's answer, this is possible... but I would not call it advisable. It's a good idea to treat the Django admin as a low-level interface for top-level technical administration; if you have user-facing object manipulation, it's usually simpler and better to handle this with ModelForm or Form views and templates that can easily be altered/updated without worrying about what might change in the admin package, which is also a lot more complex to skin/alter, should those requirements come up. Particularly for multi-tenancy, I think this is a much more maintainable and debuggable approach.

Answer (score 1):

The [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/admin/#how-do-i-limit-admin-access-so-that-objects-can-only-be-edited-by-the-users-who-created-them) way to do this is to define [`has_change_permission()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission):

```
@admin.register(Guest)
class GuestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(user=request.user)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return (obj is None or obj.user == request.user)
```

No need to muck about with the form.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of that method. Works like a champ.